# Could not import 'rosidl_typesupport_c' for package 'sensor_msgs' ROS2 python NavSatFix

Tags: python, ros2

I'm trying to make a publisher for a Ublox GPS sensor, but I'm getting this ROS error:

> ubuntu@fieldrover:~/field-rover-gps/gps/gps_pkg$ cd
> ~/field-rover-gps/gps/gps_pkg/ && colcon build && . install/setup.bash
> && ros2 run gps_pkg gps
>
> Starting >>> gps_pkg Finished <<< gps_pkg [2.98s]
>
> Summary: 1 package finished [3.49s] Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rosidl_generator_py/import_type_support_impl.py",
> line 46, in import_type_support
> return importlib.import_module(module_name, package=pkg_name)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in
> import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 657, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 556, in module_from_spec
> File "", line 1166, in
> create_module   File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: /opt/ros/galactic/lib/libgeometry_msgs__rosidl_generator_c.so:
> undefined symbol: std_msgs__msg__Header__copy
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ubuntu/field-rover-gps/gps/gps_pkg/install/gps_pkg/lib/gps_pkg/gps",
> line 33, in 
> sys.exit(load_entry_point('gps-pkg==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'gps')())   File
> "/home/ubuntu/field-rover-gps/gps/gps_pkg/install/gps_pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gps_pkg/gps.py",
> line 49, in main
> gps_node = GpsNode()   File "/home/ubuntu/field-rover-gps/gps/gps_pkg/install/gps_pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gps_pkg/gps.py",
> line 17, in **init**
> self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(NavSatFix, 'gps/fix', 10)   File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/node.py",
> line 1282, in create_publisher
> check_is_valid_msg_type(msg_type)   File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/type_support.py",
> line 35, in check_is_valid_msg_type
> check_for_type_support(msg_type)   File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/type_support.py",
> line 29, in check_for_type_support
> msg_or_srv_type.**class**.**import_type_support**()   File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sensor_msgs/msg/_nav_sat_fix.py",
> line 34, in **import_type_support**
> module = import_type_support('sensor_msgs')   File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rosidl_generator_py/import_type_support_impl.py",
> line 48, in import_type_support
> raise UnsupportedTypeSupport(pkg_name) rosidl_generator_py.import_type_support_impl.UnsupportedTypeSupport:
> Could not import 'rosidl_typesupport_c' for package 'sensor_msgs'

It seems to have an issue with NavSatFix. I've tested other sensor_msgs types like Image in the same package, and that works fine. Here's the code I tried running.

```
import rclpy
import os
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatStatus
from std_msgs.msg import Header
import serial
from ublox_gps import UbloxGps

port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=38400, timeout=1)
gps = UbloxGps(port)

class GpsNode(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('gps_node')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(NavSatFix, 'gps/fix', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)

    def timer_callback(self):
            msg = NavSatFix()
            msg.header = Header()
            msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
            msg.header.frame_id = "gps"

            msg.status.status = NavSatStatus.STATUS_FIX
            msg.status.service = NavSatStatus.SERVICE_GPS

            geo = gps.geo_coords()
            # Position in degrees.
            msg.latitude = geo.lat
            msg.longitude = geo.lon

            # Altitude in metres.
            #msg.altitude = 1.15

            msg.position_covariance[0] = 0
            msg.position_covariance[4] = 0
            msg.position_covariance[8] = 0
            msg.position_covariance_type = NavSatFix.COVARIANCE_TYPE_DIAGONAL_KNOWN

            self.publisher_.publish(msg)
            self.best_pos_a = None

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    gps_node = GpsNode()

    rclpy.spin(gps_node)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    gps_node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just using the nmea_navsat_driver found [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/tree/ros2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I forgot to add the dependency of the message type I was using in a service in the CMakeLists.txt
The dependency was missing in the rosidl_generate_interfaces